# How to permanently start kodi with ALSA?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, kodi

Im New to ubuntu and found out that pulseaudio dosent support HD audio passthrough. Found a code that starts kodi from the terminal with ALSA and then I get passthrough and dTS hd aND true hd. But is theres a way to permanently start kodi with passthrough?

When I use kodi from the command line on the left I only get stereo sound.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Do you want to just want to run kodi with passthrough on system startup?

Comment: link to the guide you are following please ....

Comment: since your google seems broken =) http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux#Installing_Kodi_on_Ubuntu-based_distributions

Comment: Here is the guidehttp://askubuntu.com/questions/585489/enabling-7-1-audio-passthru-in-14-04-for-kodi

Comment: I want to run kodi with passthrough enabled so I get hd audio. I have installed kodi the way you linken and that works but not with hd audio,only stereo. When I run the code from the link I get hd audio. But then I have to start kodi with that code from terminal every time?

Comment: By " command line on the left" You mean the launcher icons, right ? You want one of them to start kodi with your command, correct ? That's really easy if you give me the command you used.

Comment: use the start up script from that post and run it at login

Comment: Its AE_SINK=ALSA kodi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we will add your command to a [bash script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting)

Open gedit and paste this into a new document

```
#!/bin/bash         

AE_SINK=ALSA kodi
```

Now save this to your /home as `kodi.sh`.

Now right click this file and go to properties then permissions and check allow executing file as a program

Now make another new text file and paste this in to it YOU MUST CHANGE *USER* IN THE `EXEC`LINE TO YOUR USER NAME or it wont work

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec'/home/*USER*/kodi.sh'
Terminal=False
Name=Custom Kodi launcher
Comment=Any comment you want here
Icon=/path/to/icon/you/want
```

Save it as whatever and where ever you like but end it with `.desktop`.

Now right click this file and go to `properties` then `permissions` and check `allow executing file as a program`.

You can add a comment in the `comment` section of the script or an custom icon via the `icon` parameter.

When you click the .desktop file, the command in `kodi.sh` will be executed.

You can add the .desktop file to the launcher by simply dragging and draping it on there.

Comment: If this answer helped you please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to find this information easily.

Comment: I did this now but when I try to run it it I get :an error occured starting the program.  I followed this guide but I didnt specify an icon. Ive tried with out the icon line also but same error.

Comment: OK I have tested this and you are right, but I have fixed it, don't know why it won't run from there but easy fix :) see update answer.

Comment: Great, thx! Testing it after work today!