# Skullcandy plyr1 spdif output

Tags: spdif

I would like to use spdif output to my plyr1 headphones, but as skullcandy doesn't have a setup guide for them on ubuntu, I don't know how to. Could anyone instruct me on how to do this?

This is where you find the tutorials for windows and mac: http://www.skullcandy.com/customer-service/plyr-1-pc-setup/plyr-1-pc-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

The PLYR1 instructions refer to Sound Control Panel for Windows in order to choose S/PDIF. To do the equivalent then, for Ubuntu, the first thing should be to get to your Sound preferences.

1. click your system tray sound icon
2. sound settings

alternatively, you may choose to use Dash, search `Sound` to find and open the Sound Preferences.

Depending on your version of Ubuntu, there will be a tab labeled as `Output` or `Output Devices`.

There, find and choose `S/PDIF`, something resembling:

[image: Sound preferences, Output showing S/PDIF]

Image from [Enabling 7.1 audio passthru in 14.04 for Kodi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585489/enabling-7-1-audio-passthru-in-14-04-for-kodi/585735)

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 and cannot find the port setting you mentioned. Do you know where I would look to find this?

Comment: If not, then what are the other port options available to you? Additionally, can you take a screenshot of what you see when you get to this Output or Output Devices tab? Thanks