# 5.1 audio via HDMI only plays on two channels

Tags: sound, hdmi

I have my Intel NUC54250 hooked up to my TV via HDMI, and then my TV is connected to my speakers via S/PDIF. I've configured Ubuntu 16.04 to output 5.1 surround sound via HDMI. Here's the configuration in the built-in sound panel and PAVUControl:
[image: Sound control]
[image: PAVU Control]

When I use the built-in Ubuntu speaker test, however, only the left and right front speakers play sound. If I click on any other speakers, I just get silence.
[image: speaker test]

I know that my receiver and speakers work and are configured correctly, because other devices hooked up via HDMI play 5.1 audio just fine.

What's really bizarre to me is that Ubuntu *knows* that the HDMI out supports 5.1 and is configured to use it. But for whatever reason, no sound comes out on most speakers.

I'm guessing this is either an internal problem with Ubuntu or the NUC, or a problem with the HDMI full-to-mini adapter on the NUC HDMI port. But I'm leaning towards Ubuntu. If it was a problem with the adapter, I would expect *no* channels to work, rather than just left/right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out!

tl;dr: the problem was the S/PDIF link between my TV and speakers, which can only carry two uncompressed audio channels.

What triggered my understanding and a very deep dive down the rabbit hole of various incompatible drivers, audio containers/codecs, and cable types was this forum post: http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/59518-6-working-connected-hdmi-optical#561415

Basically, the problem is that when I do that speaker test, Ubuntu is outputting uncompressed 5.1 audio over HDMI. My TV receives that and tries to transmit it to my speakers over S/PDIF, but S/PDIF only supports 2 channels of uncompressed audio! So, it gets downsampled to only 2 channels.

I was fooled into thinking this should work because I've obviously played 5.1 audio over S/PDIF prior to this, but what I didn't realize is that it was encoded via Dolby or DTS to work over S/PDIF.

It seems like my possible solutions are:

1. Continue to output 5.1 uncompressed audio and replace my S/PDIF cable with an HDMI cable.
2. Change PulseAudio to output 2 channel audio and enable DTS/AC3 passthru both in PulseAudio and Kodi, as described here: [Enabling 7.1 audio passthru in 14.04 for Kodi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/585489/enabling-7-1-audio-passthru-in-14-04-for-kodi)

I'm not sure that either has a particular advantage. Option 2 involves fewer cables, but if I try to play a file with 5.1 channel PCM encoding (I imagine that's pretty rare) I'll be out of luck.

Another thing that wasn't obvious to me in setting up PAVU Control is that Dolby technically AC3, and Dolby Plus is EAC3.

Comment: Thank you!! My Aureon MKII on Ubuntu 18.04 did not play 5.1 sound. But with installing `pavucontrol` I could fix it. Here is how it is done: In `pavucontrol` goto configuration tab and select _Analog Surround 5.1 Output_ as profile! Superb!

Answer (score 2):

Probably just a matter of configuration, surround audio in Ubuntu is well developed technology. On Ubuntu 18.04, I downloaded **PulseAudio Volume Control** from the Ubuntu Store and use it to configure HDMI audio, which can be set to 2 channel stereo, 5.1 surround or 7.1 surround for my case. You can try that to see if this is just a case of configurating the audio output.

Comment: I was previously configuring audio with the built-in Ubuntu sound panel. I installed PulseAudio Volume Control but it seems to be nearly identical. I can't see anything to configure there that would help.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, the sound settings allow for the selection of different profiles when the appropriate 5.1 or 7.1 channels are available, it will allow you to select them in addition to the stereo profile.