# bluetooth audio skips and stutters

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, hp

I have an envy x360 and on windows everything works fine but on ubuntu the bluetooth audio starts skipping after a few minutes of listening.
here's an output of lspci | grep Network

```
 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
```

Comment: I am afraid this can be fixed only by switching Wi-Fi to 5 GHz.

Comment: I'll try that, with a hostspot on my phone. I unfortunately have a router that only supports 2.4 ghz, is there any reason for that though?

Comment: which media player you are using ? if vlc. please try a different media player like :- firefox, chrome, parole media player . I am using wifi at same time and it's working..

Answer (score 2):

I also tried a lot of solutions, many of which were [listed in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475987/a2dp-on-pulseaudio-terrible-choppy-skipping-audio), but none of them worked. Finally [the answer as a comment to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293131/bluetooth-audio-skips-and-stutters#comment2195914_1293131) helped out - with or without the other solutions - the 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi was causing the problem.

Turning it off and listening to music from spotify offline was no longer choppy, using a 5 GHz Wi-Fi hotspot was OK, so now I've switched to a wired connection. I was going to be upgrading my router to a 5 GHz one anyway...

A possible explanation might be that the bluetooth and Wifi share the same antenna. The bug that seems to be causing this - [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/405294). It is explained there that a fix for it would be released in pulseaudio 12. The version that ships with ubuntu 18.04 is `Version: 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.11`.
I tried manually upgrading that to version 12 ([per this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135846/1155646)) and I succeeded (`Version: 1:12.2-9~bionic1`), but that did not stop the stuttering for me.

P.S. Using an HP Probook 440 G7, Ubuntu 18.04